# How to read a horizontal file from R line by line to a table

Tags: r

I want to read a file as described at

http://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-RfA.html

into a data frame in R.

I know the function `read.table` but I think it works only with vertical table.

How should I read a file like above.

The file format is:

```
SRC:Guettarda
TGT:Lord Roem
VOT:1
RES:1
YEA:2013
DAT:19:53, 25 January 2013
TXT:'''Support''' per [[WP:DEAL]]: clueful, and unlikely to break Wikipedia.
```

So I want to read the file into a dataframe with 7 columns `SRC, TGT, ... TXT`.

Comment: You can try `readLines` to read each line and then parse it out and use `rbind` and `cbind` to create a data frame.

Comment: Thanks @Gopala, but is there a faster way and more elegant way to do that?

Comment: Unless there is a package written for this specific file format, I don't see how a general purpose thing can help. You can look at the `readr` package for some things, but I don't imagine it will solve this specific problem.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891841/importing-only-every-nth-row-from-a-csv-file-in-r

Comment: Hi @chinsoon12, thanks for your answer but I could not see the link between two questions

Comment: Hi @Gopala, I thought this file format is just a transpose version of CSV format, isn't it? Maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a method using readLines

```
dataStartPosn <- 5
nfields <- 7
TXTmaxLen <- 1e3
eachColnameLen <- 3

#download and read lines
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-RfA.txt.gz",temp)
dataLines <- readLines(gzfile(temp, "r"))

library(plyr)
library(stringi)

#extract data
data <- stri_sub(dataLines, dataStartPosn, length=TXTmaxLen)

#extract colnames
colnames <- unname(sapply(dataLines[1:(nfields+1)], function(x) substring(x, 1, eachColnameLen)))

#form table
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, split(data, ceiling(seq_along(data)/(nfields+1)))))

#formatting
df <- setNames(df, colnames)
df[-(nfields+1)]
```

---

Alternative method mentioned in comments was too slow

```
SRC <- read.csv(pipe("sed -n '1~8p' wiki-RfA.txt"))
TGT <- read.csv(pipe("sed -n '2~8p' wiki-RfA.txt"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is elegant solution.
I saved your example to ascii file "testdat".  One thing you might want to consider first is that your delimiter also crops up in your data. This makes handling the data more difficult, and it should be fairly trivial for you to change this prior to writing the data in.  I changed it to this...

SRC;Guettarda

TGT;Lord Roem

VOT;1

RES;1

YEA;2013

DAT;19:53, 25 January 2013

TXT;'''Support''' per [[WP:DEAL]]: clueful, and unlikely to break Wikipedia.

i.e. replaced the delimiting colons with semi-colons.

Then it's easy,

```
t<-read.table("testdat", stringsAsFactors=F, sep=";")

p=as.data.frame(t(t$V2), stringsAsFactors=F) 

colnames(p)<-t$V1
```

then p is what you want